# I successfully authenticated on Github via my SSH key, but how do I clone / push / pull (private) repos?

Tags: github

I followed the official explanation on Github on how to register my SSH key, and according to their [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection), everything should work:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

Unfortunately, this does not tell how to clone / push / pull repositories, and there is not documentation on that anywhere.

For example, having freshly created a new (private) repository, I have copied the repository address and tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/myusername/mynewrepository.git
```

I merely received

```
Cloning into 'mynewrepository'...
Username for 'https://github.com': myusername
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myusername/mynewrepository.git/'
```

**Question:** What are the exact commands to perform Git operations on a (private) repository on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git clone git@github.com:myusername/mynewrepository.git` to clone via ssh

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your SSH key for git operations, use:

`git clone git@github.com:myusername/mynewrepository.git`

...as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories). The SSH key does not affect any HTTPS based connection